# Version check of a program in bash

Tags: bash, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a simple if switch in bash, if the version of ionic is 3.4.0:

```
mles:operations-ionic mles$ node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic -v
3.4.0
mles:operations-ionic mles$ if [[ "$(node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic -v)" = "3.4.0" ]]; then echo "Ionic3 Project"; fi
mles:operations-ionic mles$
```

This should output `Ionic3 Project` to the console, but it doesn't. Why?

@Inian: I'm writing to stdout. A simple comparision does write to the console:

```
mles:operations-ionic mles$ if [[ "1" = "1" ]]; then echo "Ionic3 Project"; fi
Ionic3 Project
mles:operations-ionic mles$
```

and the trick with storing the version to a variable does not do anything:

```
mles:operations-ionic mles$ version=$(node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic -v); if [[ "${version}" = "3.4.0" ]]; then echo "Ionic3 Project"; fi
mles:operations-ionic mles$
```

@camh no invisible characters. saved it to a script:

```
version=$(node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic -v)
if [[ ${version} == "3.4.0" ]]; then
  echo "Ionic3 Project";
fi
printf '<%s>' "${version}"
```

output:

```
mles:operations-ionic mles$ ./jenkins.sh 
3.4.0>mles:operations-ionic mles$
```

Comment: Are you sure it is writing to `stdout`? what happens when you try and store it in a variable? i.e. `version=$(node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic -v)`?

Comment: You're comparing two strings - have the $(....) by itself without the quotes.  EDIT: Sorry - forget this !

Comment: After saving the output in a variable, print it out with delimiters: `printf '<%s>' "${version}"`. There may be spaces after the number, and this will show you if there are some invisible characters in the version string.

Comment: use `set -x` inside your bash console/script to see what bash is doing with your code. It's a good way to debug bash scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the ionic developers messed up the version number with hidden characters. If you pipe the command to `cat -A`, which display non-printable characters, you'll realize that there are indeed hidden characters in front of it:

```
ionic --version | cat -A
^[[2K^[[G3.4.0$
```

(The `$` at the end is just the newline)

Actually I think that should be fixed on ionic side. I've [filed a bug](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12300).

A workaround for you to use would be:

```
version="$(ionic info | awk '/Ionic CLI/{print $NF}')"
```

---

**Update:**

The problem has been fixed in https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/commit/cb448dbe535ab77d5feb07090de962e17290e557. It should disappear in the next release (after 3.4.0).